# Can an old graphics card support a new LCD monitor?

Tags: display, graphics-card

I'm trying to "revive" my old pc (bought around 1998) but I'm missing its original 15 inch CRT monitor.

Instead I'm trying to connect it to my new 23 inch LCD using a VGA adaptor. Unfortunately it displays nothing (no signal). So, is this technically possible or the 23 inches are waaaay too much for this old guy?

PS: The graphics card is an old ATI 3D Rage Pro with 8MB (lol!) RAM.

Comment: It should work fine, VGA is VGA is VGA.  Exactly what kind of "VGA adapter" are you speaking of?  Are you using a VGA input on the LCD, or something else?

Comment: I see no reason it shouldn't work.  The two reasons it wouldn't work is A) the current GPU doesn't actually work B) The monitor does not support the resolutions the GPU does support.  I suspect **A** myself.

Comment: Assuming that the monitor has inputs for VGA, DVI and possibly HDMI and DisplayPort, do you have the monitor set to Analog input?

Comment: Your BIOS will be VGA, so if you can see your initial BIOS screens (memory and disc configurations), then VGA is OK. If not, try using your adapter on a newer system first, so as to verify it. Are you sure there is no VGA port on the monitor itself? Most monitors still have them, as do most TVs.

Comment: It is a DVI to VGA adapter [link](https://www.google.gr/search?q=VGA&es_sm=122&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=NGa9U5iLC6biywPYl4KQDw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=927#q=DVI+to+VGA&tbm=isch&imgdii=_). It works ok with my current system. Is there a way to verify that my graphics card is still functional?

Comment: Presumably you mean VGA (on the graphics card) to DVI (on the monitor)?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a VGA port on your monitor, it should work. However, the video card cannot run the monitor at its native resolution (23-inch monitors are generally 1920×1080). 1990s video cards like the 3D Rage Pro simply were not designed to handle resolutions anywhere near full HD, and the notion of "high definition" simply wasn't mainstream back then.

If you need to use legacy hardware, you might want to get a 19-inch 1280×1024 display instead. 1280×1024 is the maximum resolution the ATI 3D Rage Pro supports, and these monitors can be had for around US$100. I'd suggest the [Acer V196L](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1019735-REG/acer_um_cv6aa_005_v196l_b_19_monitor.html); I've used the older V193 model and it's not bad for a cheap monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the info! However is there a way to check if the 3D Rage Pro is still functioning before investing on a monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern monitors should still cope with much lower resolutions even if they have to do some horrible looking interpolation.

I would [double check](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/pc-peripheral/3365585/how-tell-dvi-i-dvi-d-cables-apart/) that your VGA to DVI cable supports analogue signals. It's possible your cable only supports a digital connection and your rather ancient VGA card is only producing an analogue one..

Answer (score 0):

Your LCD needs to support DVI-A, DVI-I Single Link, or DVI-I Dual Link. Your monitor only supports analog. Your DVI to VGA adapter by hardware specs is analog only. The only unknown is your monitor and whether it supports an analog mode. DVI was introduced in 1999. It doesn't sound like your LCD is that old, so it might not have DVI-A. You will likely need to get an older monitor that has VGA or DVI-A. You can go to any GoodWill or second hand store and they will likely have a CRT for cheap.

http://www.datapro.net/techinfo/dvi_info.html